# GDB not seeing correct function argument values even though they are set

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, 64-bit

First time trying to debug on a quad-core Xeon after 15 years of successful x86 GDB use.

Linux DellT3500 3.16.0-23-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 21 17:56:17 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.8-1ubuntu4) 7.8.0.20141001-cvs

g++ compiler flags:

```
-Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wchar-subscripts -Wparentheses -gstabs+ -DLINUX  -O0
```

Setting a breakpoint in a certain class member function shows **this=0x0** and the other parameter incorrectly when the breakpoint happens.  But inserting a **printf** in the code right after that shows that **this** and the parameter are actually set correctly:

```
Breakpoint 1, PlayGamePage::actionPerformed (this=0x0, inTarget=0x7fffffffdf90)
    at PlayGamePage.cpp:725
725     printf( "hey, this = %x, inTarget = %x\n", this );
(gdb) next
hey, this = b6cc50, inTarget = b6ce18
727   if( inTarget == &mCommitButton &&
(gdb) print this
$1 = (PlayGamePage * const) 0x0
(gdb) print inTarget
$2 = (GUIComponent *) 0x7fffffffdf90
(gdb)
```

But you can see how GDB can't even print these values correctly, even though they are set and printable by the code with **printf**.  This is is a big problem, because GDB has no access to printing member variables.

Also, the rest of the function body uses **this** extensively and inTarget extensively (accessing class members and testing inTarget), and the code functions as expected.  No crashes or misbehavior, so this is set correctly in the code, but GDB can't see it.

Going up the stack:

```
(gdb) up
#1  0x000000000040a11f in ActionListenerList::fireActionPerformed (
    this=0xb6cf98, inTarget=0xb6cf48)
    at ../../minorGems/ui/event/ActionListenerList.h:134
134         listener->actionPerformed( inTarget );
```

See that **inTarget** matches what **printf** sees down in the **actionPerformed** function body.  Also, gdb can print these values fine at this point:

```
(gdb) print inTarget
$5 = (GUIComponent *) 0xb6cf48
(gdb) print listener
$6 = (ActionListener *) 0xb6ce18
```

**listener** should match **this** down in the function body, and it does according to printf, but gdb sees **this=0x0** instead.

Yes, this is a virtual function that is being called (PlayGamePage implements the ActionListener interface, overriding the actionPerformed virtual function).

I just placed a breakpoint in exactly the same code in GDB on 32-bit x86, and it sees both this and inTarget correctly and can print them correctly, with values matching what the code's printf shows.

Answer (score 0):

This is either a bug in your GCC (which version are you using?) or a bug in GDB.

Since you are apparently running an *old* CVS snapshot of GDB, I suggest first trying a *stable* GDB release instead.